# 2D array not printing out in grid/not full array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

The issue I'm having is that the 2D array is not printing out everything in the array, and when I run the evolve method, it doesn't print out the 2D array the same as the first time. Wondering what's wrong to make it not print out the entire array, and not print the array the same way when the evolve method runs? Each print out of the array needs to be in a 25x75 grid

Desired initial result: 
[image]

Actual result:

[image]

evolve method result: 
[image]
Project 4:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Created a scanner
        System.out.println("Enter the file name you would like to use");
        File file = new File(input.nextLine()); // Takes file name to find file
        Scanner inputFromFile = new Scanner(file);
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file); // reads file
        int r;
        int y = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while ((r = fileInput.read()) != -1) { // goes through each character in
                                                // file, char by char
            char c = (char) r;
            GameOfLife.grid[i][y] = c;
            y++;
            if (y == 75) {
                y = 0;
                i++;
                if (i == 25) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Prints the initial environment
        System.out.println("Initial set: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < GameOfLife.grid.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(GameOfLife.grid[j]);
        }
        boolean operate = true;
        while (operate = true) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to see the next generation? Y/N?");
            String q = input.nextLine();
            if (q.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                GameOfLife.evolve();
                for (int j = 0; j < GameOfLife.grid.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(GameOfLife.grid[j]);
                    operate = true;
                }
            } else {
                operate = false;
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GameOfLife:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GameOfLife {

    static final int m = 25; // number of rows
    static final int n = 75; // number of columns
    static char[][] grid = new char[m][n]; // Creates an empty (no dots or
                                            // X's)grid of rows and columns.

    static int count_neighbors(int i, int j) {
        int nn = 0; // number of neighbors of cell(i,j)

        if (i > 0 && j > 0 && grid[i - 1][j - 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (i > 0 && grid[i - 1][j] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (i > 0 && j < 72 && grid[i - 1][j + 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (j > 0 && grid[i][j - 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (j < 72 && grid[i][j + 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (j > 0 && i < 22 && grid[i + 1][j - 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (i < 22 && grid[i + 1][j] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }
        ;
        if (i < 22 && j < 72 && grid[i + 1][j + 1] == 'X') {
            nn++;
        }

        return nn;
    }

    static void evolve() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 73; j++) {
                int s = count_neighbors(i, j);
                if (s < 2) {
                    grid[i][j] = '.';
                }
                if (s == 2 || s == 3) {
                    grid[i][j] = 'X';
                }
                if (s > 3) {
                    grid[i][j] = '.';
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You should be more specific than what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `System.out.println()` after each for-loop to start printing the grid on the next line.

```
// Print out grid.length characters
for (int j = 0; j < GameOfLife.grid.length; j++) {
    System.out.print(GameOfLife.grid[j]);
}
// Print a new line
System.out.println();
```

**Updated**

The problem I failed to notice above is that you are printing an entire row in one line, and the whole grid in one (visible) loop. The following `System.out.println()` would therefore print a blank line after the entire grid is printed. Please see my solution which extracts out the printing of the game, uses a try-catch for the file reader, and removes the unnecessary `operate` variable at the bottom since you were just exiting anyway.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project4 {

    private static void printGame() {
        for (char[] row : GameOfLife.grid) {
            for (char c : row) {
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Created a scanner
        System.out.println("Enter the file name you would like to use");
        File file = new File(input.nextLine()); // Takes file name to find file
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line;
        int i = 0;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int col = 0; col < line.length(); col++) {
                    GameOfLife.grid[i][col] = line.charAt(col);
                }
                i++;
                if (i == 25) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        }

        // Prints the initial environment
        System.out.println("Initial set: ");
        printGame();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to see the next generation? Y/N?");
            String q = input.nextLine();
            if (q.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                GameOfLife.evolve();
                printGame();
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im not exactly sure where you mean?

Comment: Updated answer. I assume you are viewing your output with word-wrap on. If you turn that off, I think you would see what I mean.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but the output is still as follows:
 initial set: http://prntscr.com/8txg58 
evolve method: http://prntscr.com/8txgef
first one is not in a grid, and again for some reason the second grid for evolve doesn't fill the entire 25x75 grid

Comment: I figured out the problem. Your FileInputSteam is reading in carriage returns at the end of your text file `\r\n` is being set as the first two character in your grid. I will update the answer in a second.

Comment: Also, your evolve logic is wrong, I think the `X`'s are being cascaded down the rows. You can either figure that one out yourself or post another question about that since it is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using `println` this in both places like this:

```
System.out.println(GameOfLife.grid[j]);
```

`System.out.print()` is not flushed automatically, it's only flushed when a newline is written.  This means that rather than writing out everything, it might buffer the IO to keep things more efficient.